# ros2 humble: how to log a message after CTRL+C

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I'm used to use this kind of main function:

```
    try:
        rclpy.spin(rc_node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        rc_node.get_logger().info('[RC_NODE] Received Keyboard Interrupt (^C). Shutting down.')

    # rc_node.shutdown()
    # Destroy the node explicitly
    # (optional - otherwise it will be done automatically
    # when the garbage collector destroys the node object)
    rc_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()
```

but on humble I've read that things has changed and now I have to use something like:

```
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    rc_node = RadioControlNode()

    try:
        rclpy.spin(rc_node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    except ExternalShutdownException:
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:
      rc_node.destroy_node()
      rclpy.try_shutdown()
```

I would like to add `rc_node.get_logger().info('[RC_NODE] Received Keyboard Interrupt (^C). Shutting down.')` but adding that line gives me an error on console:

```
^C[INFO] [1710356025.545294766] [rc_node]: [RC_NODE] Received Keyboard Interrupt (^C). Shutting down.
Failed to publish log message to rosout: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:423
```

What is the proper way of doing this?